# Precise determinant of integer NxN matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, math, linear-algebra

Determinant definition has only additions, subtractions and multiplications. So a determinant of a matrix with integer elements **must be integer**.

However `numpy.linalg.det()` returns a "slightly off" floating-point number:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> M = [[-1 if i==j else 1 for j in range(7)] for i in range(7)]
>>> numpy.linalg.det(M)
319.99999999999994
```

It gets worse for a larger matrix:

```
>>> M = [[-1024 if i==j else 1024 for j in range(7)] for i in range(7)]
>>> numpy.linalg.det(M)
3.777893186295698e+23
>>> "%.0f" % numpy.linalg.det(M)
'377789318629569805156352'
```

And it's wrong! I'm sure the correct answer is:

```
>>> 320 * 1024**7
377789318629571617095680
```

Of course, for a big matrix it may be a rather long integer. But python has long integers built in.

How can I get an *exact integer value* of the determinant instead of approximate floating point value?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple practical way to calculate determinant of an integet matrix is [Bareiss algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bareiss_algorithm).

```py
def det(M):
    M = [row[:] for row in M] # make a copy to keep original M unmodified
    N, sign, prev = len(M), 1, 1
    for i in range(N-1):
        if M[i][i] == 0: # swap with another row having nonzero i's elem
            swapto = next( (j for j in range(i+1,N) if M[j][i] != 0), None )
            if swapto is None:
                return 0 # all M[*][i] are zero => zero determinant
            M[i], M[swapto], sign = M[swapto], M[i], -sign
        for j in range(i+1,N):
            for k in range(i+1,N):
                assert ( M[j][k] * M[i][i] - M[j][i] * M[i][k] ) % prev == 0
                M[j][k] = ( M[j][k] * M[i][i] - M[j][i] * M[i][k] ) // prev
        prev = M[i][i]
    return sign * M[-1][-1]
```

This algorithm is reasonably fast (*O(N³)* complexity).

And it's an *integer preserving* algorithm. It does have a division. But as long as all the elements of M are integer, all intermediate calculations would be integer too (the division remainder will be zero).

As a bonus the same code **works for fractions/floating-point/complex** elements if you drop the `assert` line and replace the integer division `//` with a regular division `/`.

---

> PS: Another alternative is to use **sympy** instead of numpy:
>
> ```
> >>> import sympy
> >>> sympy.Matrix([ [-1024 if i==j else 1024 for j in range(7)] for i in range(7) ]).det()
> 377789318629571617095680
> ```
>
> But somewhy that is MUCH slower than the above `det()` function.
>
> ```
> # Performance test: `numpy.linalg.det(M)` vs `det(M)` vs `sympy.Matrix(M).det()`
> import timeit
> def det(M):
>     ...
> M = [[-1024 if i==j else 1024 for j in range(7)] for i in range(7)]
> print(timeit.repeat("numpy.linalg.det(M)", setup="import numpy; from __main__ import M", number=100, repeat=5))
> #: [0.0035009384155273, 0.0033931732177734, 0.0033941268920898, 0.0033800601959229, 0.0033988952636719]
> print(timeit.repeat("det(M)", setup="from __main__ import det, M", number=100, repeat=5))
> #: [0.0171120166778564, 0.0171020030975342, 0.0171608924865723, 0.0170948505401611, 0.0171010494232178]
> print(timeit.repeat("sympy.Matrix(M).det()", setup="import sympy; from __main__ import M", number=100, repeat=5))
> #: [0.9561479091644287, 0.9564781188964844, 0.9539868831634521, 0.9536828994750977, 0.9546608924865723]
> ```
>
> Summary:
>
> - `det(M)` is 5+ times slower than `numpy.linalg.det(M)`,
> - `det(M)` is **~50 times faster** than `sympy.Matrix(M).det()`
>
> It becomes even faster without the `assert` line.

Answer (score 6):

@pycoder's answer is the preferred solution; for comparison, I wrote a Gaussian elimination function using the [`Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) class which allows exact arithmetic of rational numbers. It is about 11 times slower than the Bareiss algorithm on the same benchmark.

```py
from fractions import Fraction

def det(matrix):
    matrix = [[Fraction(x, 1) for x in row] for row in matrix]
    n = len(matrix)
    d, sign = 1, 1
    for i in range(n):
        if matrix[i][i] == 0:
            j = next((j for j in range(i + 1, n) if matrix[j][i] != 0), None)
            if j is None:
                return 0
            matrix[i], matrix[j] = matrix[j], matrix[i]
            sign = -sign
        d *= matrix[i][i]
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            factor = matrix[j][i] / matrix[i][i]
            for k in range(i + 1, n):
                matrix[j][k] -= factor * matrix[i][k]
    return int(d) * sign
```