# Exact Value In Determinant Using Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, determinants

I want to compute the determinant of a 2*2 matrix , and I use linalg.det from Numpy like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([
[1,2],
[3,4]
])
b=np.linalg.det(a)
```

In other hand, We know that we also can compute it by a multiplication and a subtract like this:

```
1*4 - 2*3 = -2
```

But when I set b equal to -2 :

```
b == -2
```

It returns false.

What is the problem here? And How can I fix it?

Comment: `b`, which is here `-2.0000000000000004`, is not equal to `-2`. Are you trying to change the value of `b`, or check if it is `-2`?

Comment: Floating point error I believe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Precise determinant of integer NxN matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66192894/precise-determinant-of-integer-nxn-matrix)

Comment: For exact answers you could try sympy (making sure you avoid floats in the input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with integers, you can use

```py
b = int(np.linalg.det(a))
```

To just make it into an integer. This should give you the following

```py
int(b) == -2 ## Returns True
```

Edit: This doesn't work if the approximation is something like -1.99999999999. As per JohanC in the comments below, try using int(round(b)) instead.

Comment: This is dangeous. When the floating point approximation would result in `-1.99999999999` you'd round the wrong way.

Comment: You could try `int(round(b))` instead.