# Cramer's rule function in python returns answers with decimal point

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, equation

I have the following function in python:

```
def cramer(coef_matrix, free_coef_matrix):

    num_rows, num_cols = coef_matrix.shape

    if num_rows != num_cols:
        raise Exception("Cannot apply cramer's rule to a non-square matrix")

    determinant = np.linalg.det(coef_matrix)

    if determinant == 0:
        raise Exception("Cannot apply cramer's rule to a matrix with determinant 0")

    solution = num_rows*[0]

    for i in range(num_rows):
        coef_matrix_copy = coef_matrix.copy()
        coef_matrix_copy[:, i] = free_coef_matrix
        current_det = np.linalg.det(coef_matrix_copy)
        solution[i] = current_det / determinant

    return solution
```

But the problem is when I run the function on the input:

```
coef_matrix:
[2, 1, 1],
[1, -1, -1]
[1, 2, 1]

free_coef_matrix:
[3, 0, 0]
```

It returns `[1.0, -2.0000000000000004, 3.0]` instead of `[1.0, -2.0, 3.0]`.
I know that there might be problems related to floating point, but I want to know if there might be a solution?

Comment: Do you expect `current_det` and `determinant` to be integers?  If so, have you tried printing them in the loop to verify?

Comment: This is a more precise answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66192894/precise-determinant-of-integer-nxn-matrix . Also, a single division operator / is gonna give you a float either way, use //.